# UI-Grid: columns resizing ends in overflowing the grid

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a grid that consists of several columns. I defined columnDefs including width and min width. In addition I have disabled the horizontal scrollbar.

When resizing the columns to the right they "exit" the grid and I can see them by scrolling (although there is no scroll). How can I force the columns to stay in the grid boundaries?

- This is the regular view:
  [image]
- After resizing to the right and scrolling to the right, you can see that the "name" column is off boundaries (on the left side)
  [image]

  #### Grid Config

  ```
          columnDefs: this.queueConfig.columns,
          rowHeight: 24,
          rowTemplate: rowtpl,
          enableHorizontalScrollbar: this.uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
          enableColumnMenus: false,
          enableRowSelection: true,
          enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
          enableFiltering: true,
          modifierKeysToMultiSelect: true,
          multiSelect: true
  ```

#### Column Definitions

- This is a function that returns the columnDefs for the grid.
- The details are not important, only to notice the width definition for our issue.

  ```
   private buildGridColumns(): any {

      const colMinWidth = "100";
      const columnsMap = {
          name: {
              name: this.$translate.instant('Name'),
              field: "documentName",
              minWidth: colMinWidth
          },
          step: {
              name: this.$translate.instant('Col_Step'),
              field: "status",
              width: "150",
              minWidth: colMinWidth,
              cellFilter: "printStatus"
          },
          submitted: {
              name: "Submitted",
              field: "createdTime",
              width: "150",
              minWidth: colMinWidth,
              cellFilter: "date: 'd/M/yy h:mm a'",
              sort: {
                  direction: this.uiGridConstants.DESC
              }
          },
          pagesNum: {
              name: this.$translate.instant('NumPages'),
              field: "numPages",
              width: "80",
              minWidth: colMinWidth,
              cellFilter: "foreignDocument: this"
          },
          quantity: {
              name: this.$translate.instant('Quantity'),
              field: "numCopies",
              width: "80",
              minWidth: colMinWidth,
              cellFilter: "foreignDocument: this"
          },
          progress: {
              name: "Progress",
              field: "PercentComplete",
              minWidth: colMinWidth,
              cellTemplate:
              "<kd-progress-bar ng-if='!row.entity.isForeign' percentage='row.entity.percentComplete'></kd-progress-bar>" +
              "<div ng-if='row.entity.isForeign' class='kd-progress-unavailable'>N/A</div>"
          },
          duration: {
              name: this.$translate.instant('Duration'),
              field: "estimatedTime",
              minWidth: colMinWidth,
              cellFilter: "foreignDocument: this"
          },
          status: {
              name: this.$translate.instant('Status'),
              field: "docState",
              minWidth: colMinWidth,
              cellFilter: "documentState"
          },
          press: {
              name: this.$translate.instant('Press'),
              field: "dfeName",
              minWidth: colMinWidth
          },
          created: {
              name: this.$translate.instant('Created'),
              field: "createdDtm",
              minWidth: colMinWidth,
              cellFilter: "date: 'd/M/yy h:mm a'",
              sort: {
                  direction: this.uiGridConstants.DESC
              }
          },
          time: {
              name: this.$translate.instant("Time"),
              field: "createdTime",
              minWidth: colMinWidth,
              cellFilter: "date: 'd/M/yy h:mm a'",
              width: "120",
              sort: {
                  direction: this.uiGridConstants.DESC
              }
          },
          failTime: {
              name: this.$translate.instant('FailureTime'),
              field: "lastUpdateTime",
              minWidth: colMinWidth,
              cellFilter: "date: 'd/M/yy h:mm a'",
              width: "120",
              sort: {
                  direction: this.uiGridConstants.DESC
              }
          },
          completeTime: {
              name: this.$translate.instant('CompletionTime'),
              field: "lastUpdateTime",
              minWidth: colMinWidth,
              cellFilter: "date: 'short'",
              width: "120",
              sort: {
                  direction: this.uiGridConstants.DESC
              }
          }
      };

      return columnsMap;
  }
  ```

Comment: Could you provide a code example (like jsfiddle or codepen), please?